# periodicity of a sinusoidal function

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

$f(t) = \sin t$ has a period of $2\pi$, where $t$ = time. Using words: Each value of $f(t)$ is being repeated every $2\pi$. Using symbols: $\sin t = \sin(t+2\pi)$ which is the definition of a periodic function. That is understood, so far so good.

1. If I have $g(t) = \sin 2t$, **is $\omega_0 = 2$?** Ιf yes, then $Τ = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_0} \implies Τ= \frac{2\pi}{2} \implies Τ= \pi$. Is it correct?
2. If I have $h(t) = \sin2ωt$ now what? **Is** $\omega_0 = 2$? Maybe $\omega_0 = 2ω$?    If yes, then  $Τ = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_0} \implies Τ= \frac{2\pi}{2\omega} \implies Τ= \frac{\pi}{\omega}$ which is not the same as  $Τ = \pi$. In order to make it look like $Τ= \pi$ **how do i prove that T= π when i see sin2ωt**, without braking the math/physics rules?

**EDIT** :$\omega_0$ is just a symbol not harmonics etc i used $\omega_0$ to differentiate it from $\omega$, my bad i should have used an other symbol like $\omega_b$ , $\omega_1$ etc.

Comment: Use '_' to write subscipts in MathJax. '\omega_0', for example.

Comment: What is $\omega_0$ vs $\omega$ ?

Comment: Both represent angular frequency, my naming convention. in example 1, if the standard formula is sinωt, but instead i see  sin2t, i suppose that 2 =ωο, i give a name to value 2, ωo = 2 to make it look different from example 2. I do not know the rest (this should suffice your question).

Comment: how do i close this question or do i just let it be? After thinking it through for a day i found a convincing solution.

Answer (score 1):

A sinusoid is usually written as $\sin\omega t$ where the pulsation $\omega=\dfrac{2\pi}T$ and $T=\dfrac{2\pi}\omega$ is the period.

So $\sin2t$ denotes a sinusoid of pulsation $\omega=2$ and period $T=\dfrac{2\pi}2=\pi$.

But if you write $\sin\color{red}2\omega t$, $\omega$ no longer has the meaning of a pulsation, but is a "half-pulsation", and what you would find with $\dfrac{2\pi}\omega$ is the *double* period (while the true period is $\dfrac{2\pi}{\color{red}2\omega}$).

Due to the confusion this introduces, I advise you to stay away from such a notation.

Comment: sin2ωt i see this ALL the time when i do math in physics- related books. i do not fully understand your answer yet, my goal is to prove that T= π when i see sin2ωt. i can't stay away from that notation.

Comment: @DontAskTheEye No, you don't see that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave. Try and show me a single link. And $T=\pi$ is clearly addressed in my answer.

Comment: @DontAskTheEye: or are you speaking of *harmonics* ?

Comment: i have a math book in front of me ( it is not in english), i have one book from schaum outline series, author edminister, title electric circuits(go to the solved problems first chapter, it is flooded with sinωt, sin2ωt) and a physics book(not english). It is not harmonics. I just used a subscript for ω to help me describe. I know that the fundamental frequency is using the symbol ωο but in my case it is just a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(2\omega t+2\pi)=\sin(2\omega t)$$

Therefore,

$$\sin\left(2\omega\left(t+\frac{\pi}{\omega}\right)\right)=\sin(2\omega t)$$

That is,

$$h\left(t+\frac\pi\omega\right)=h(t)$$

So $\pi/\omega$ is a period of $h$.

Comment: the period of sin2t is T=π. How do i prove it?  i don't see that. I need to end up in a forumula which will be :  T=π.